# Reverse lines in ArrayList Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm working on a Java program in which I must read the contents of a file and then print each lines reverse. For example the text:

```
Public Class Helloprinter
Public static void
```

would print the following after running my reverse program:

```
retnirPolleh ssalc cilbup 
diov citats cilbup
```

Here's what I got so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
     // Prompt for the input and output file names
      ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); 
      //String reverse = "";
      Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Input file: ");
      String inputFileName = console.next();
      System.out.print("Output file: ");
      String outputFileName = console.next();


      // Construct the Scanner and PrintWriter objects for reading and writing

      File inputFile = new File(inputFileName);
      Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFile);
      PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outputFileName);
      String aString = ""; 

      while(in.hasNextLine())
      {           
          String line = in.nextLine(); 
          list.add(line);       
      }

      in.close(); 

      for(int i = 0; i <list.size(); i++)
      {
          aString = list.get(i); 
          aString = new StringBuffer(aString).reverse().toString();
          out.printf("%s", " " + aString); 
      }

      out.close(); 

}
```

}
EDIT:

With Robert's posting it helped put me in the right direction. The problem is that with that is that it doesn't keep the lines.

```
Public Class Helloprinter
Public static void
```

becomes after running my program:

```
retnirPolleh ssalc cilbup diov citats cilbup
```

it needs to keep the line layout the same. so it should be:

```
retnirPolleh ssalc cilbup
diov citats cilbup
```

Comment: what output are you getting?

Comment: You should probably tell us what's not working.

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in the line

```
      out.printf("%s", " " + aString);
```

This doesn't output a newline. I'm also not sure why you are sticking a space in there.

It should be either:

```
      out.println( aString );
```

Or

```
      out.printf("%s%n", aString);
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of the %n to add a new line. Thanks for pointing that out. I will keep that in mind for next time I need it!

Answer (score 0):

In your last loop why don't you just iterate through the list backwards? So:

```
for(int i = 0; i <list.size(); i++)
```

Becomes:

```
for(int i = list.size() - 1; i >=0; i--)
```

Comment: My bad on not telling the problem! Your idea did put me in the right direction, though it's still not working 100% correct.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a string builder. You were on the right trail. Probably just needed a little help. There is no "one way" to do anything, but you could try something like this:

**Note: Here is my output:** retnirPolleh ssalc cilbup diov citats cilbup

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Reverse {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> myReverseList = null;
        System.out.println("Input file: \n");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String fileName = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Output file: \n");
        String outputFileName = input.nextLine();
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
            String text = null;
            myReverseList = new ArrayList<String>();
            StringBuilder sb = null;
            try {
                while ((text = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int i = text.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                        sb.append(text.charAt(i));
                    }
                    myReverseList.add(sb.toString());
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Writer writer = null;
        try {
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                new FileOutputStream(outputFileName), "utf-8"));
            for (String s : myReverseList) {
                writer.write("" + s + "\n");
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // report
        } finally {
            try {
                writer.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you already know how to read a file, so then call this method for each line.
Note, this is recursion and it's probably not the most efficient but it's simple and it does what you want.

```
public String reverseString(final String s) {
        if (s.length() == 0)
            return s;
        // move chahctrachter at current position and then put it at the end of the string.
        return reverseString(s.substring(1)) + s.charAt(0);
    }
```